# Keep my main Activity when starting from Notification Intent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

In my App, I have MainActivity with bottom navigation. When I receive a new notification, when I click on it (to open it), I don't want to recreate my MainActivity if it already exists. So I tried to add flags, but it doesn't work at all...

Could you help me guys?

```
Intent newsFeedDetailsActivityIntent = NewsFeedDetailsActivity.newInstance(mNewsFeedId);

Intent mainActivityIntent = MainActivity.newInstance(MainActivity.createBundle(navItem, currentMs));
mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

TaskStackBuilder builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MyApplication.getInstance())
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(mainActivityIntent)
                .addNextIntent(newsFeedDetailsActivityIntent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = builder.getPendingIntent((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Set pending intent to notification
notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: you can specify android:launchMode="singleTop" with your activity in the manifest file.

Comment: @GauravPrajapati : no effect

Comment: use this only intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: @GauravPrajapati doesn't work too my friend

Comment: You can't do this using `TaskStackBuilder`. It will always recreate everything. Please post your manifest and I can show you how to do it correctly.